# RabbitMQ and authorization

Tags: authentication, rabbitmq, amqp

One of my projects requires authentication for using RabbitMQ. Only authenticated users can connect to the rabbitmq server and subscribe to queues etc. For example, when a user connects to the server for the first time and sends some auth data (like login, password) - server should check it and, if the user passed authentication, he will be able to subscribe to queues etc. Otherwise, the server would disconnect the user. Is there a solution for this?

Please don't judge too harshly, I'm not really familiar with RabbitMQ and stuff like this.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is very easy to find out yourself. A simple Google search for the terms, "RabbitMQ Authentication" returns [this page](http://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html) as the first entry:

> When an AMQP client establishes a connection to an AMQP server, it
>   specifies a virtual host within which it intends to operate. A first
>   level of access control is enforced at this point, with the server
>   checking whether the user has any permissions to access the virtual
>   hosts, and rejecting the connection attempt otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

This [amqplib documentation](https://amqp-node.github.io/amqplib/channel_api.html#connect) gives a straightforward answer.

```
Connecting with an object instead of a URL
The URL can also be supplied as an object of the form:

{
  protocol: 'amqp',
  hostname: 'localhost',
  port: 5672,
  username: 'guest',
  password: 'guest',
  locale: 'en_US',
  frameMax: 0,
  heartbeat: 0,
  vhost: '/',
}
```